# UITableView insert row decoration

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying enable editing of my `UITableView` by providing an Edit button on the nav bar.

The intention is to allow the user to insert new items and delete existing items.
When clicking the Edit button iOS shows the "Delete" decoration (deleting works fine), but doesnt show "Insert"

I have added `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem` to my `UIViewControllers viewDidLoad` and have added the following methods to my `UITableViewDataSource` delegate:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            AppDelegate.persistenceContext.delete(self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
            AppDelegate.saveContext()
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            let current = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
// do rest of insertion logic
        }
    }
```

What am I missing something?

Oh and out of interest, if this is possible would the new cell be inserted above or below the one on which the action was initiated?

For the record I can add custom swipe actions to the cells, but the users feedback is they prefer an edit button.

Any light would be appreciated, all the Googling has gotten me is using a button to insert a new row, or adding custom swipe actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle
```

Return `.delete`, `.insert`, or `.none` for a given index path. Normally only one row (typically first or last) would return `.insert` and the rest would return `.delete`. Return `.none` for any row that can't be inserted or deleted.

It's not uncommon that you also need to override the `setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)` method to add/remove an extra row just for the purposes of showing the green + (`.insert`) icon.

An alternative is to show the + icon in the nav bar instead of having a row with the insert icon.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, a row can only have one decoration on the left side?

Comment: That is correct. It would't make sense to have two.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for :) . Thanks :)

Comment: Why? It would be confusing have both insert and delete on the same row. The idea is you have delete next to rows that can be deleted and you have insert next to one row to give the user a change to add one new row to the table.

Comment: Take Numbers as an example, right click on a row and you can insert and delete from the presented context menu, in fact on iOS Delete is sandwiched between Copy and Row Actions... on the context menu.  In must application I use the edit function are usually group together.  Also in this case remember the button added to the nav bar is Edit, which suggests a collection of related functionality.  To have Insert and Delete together doesnt present as confusing to me.  However Apple has gone a different way and your answer(s) have helped me out and I have learnt something :)

Comment: You are mixing up lots of different functionality. A context menu is very different from the standard insert/delete row decorations of a table view in iOS. Look at some of Apple's apps on iOS such as Stocks, Contacts, and Weather for example of what they do.